# Is manipulating the ModelState in this way a coding mispractice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I am presented with a situation where I would like to use `Html.ValidationSummary()` in my views to display a generic error message. Maybe something like `"There was a problem with the information you entered."` but without getting a list of every single thing that went wrong (as per DataAnnotations).

*side note*: I've found references to people using `if(ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){ ... }` in their views and foregoing `ValidationSummary` altogether. I am not really impressed with that approach, to say the least.

It's important that the `ModelStateDictionary` still contains a key for each model element which had a validation error (so that `Html.EditorFor`, et al. write the correct css classes.)

What I ended up with and seems to work is:

```
public static class ModelStateHelpers
{
    public static void Empty(this ModelStateDictionary @this)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> state in @this)
        {
            if (state.Value.Errors.Any())
            {
                state.Value.Errors.Clear();
                state.Value.Errors.Add(String.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Followed by this in my class:

```
if (StuffWentWrong) {
    this.ModelState.Empty();
    this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong...");
}
```

As intended, the `Html.ValidationSummary` is smart enough to suppress html structure for `ModelStates` in the dictionary whose error messages are blank; and I also end up with text fields decorated with error validation attributes, such as `<input class="input-validation-error text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User Name field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />`

Does this particular solution smell badly?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for the ValidationSummary HtmlHelper? You might be able to use / extend / copy off of it to get what you're looking for without altering the ModelStateDictionary.

Comment: A fair point. I'll have a look at it in the morrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've found references to people using
>   `if(ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){ ... }` in their views and
>   foregoing ValidationSummary altogether. I am not really impressed with
>   that approach, to say the least.

Why not? I think this is a reasonable solution. You say you want a special use case for displaying the validation summary, which is a **view concern**. You shouldn't have to manipulate anything in the controller or otherwise *fight the framework* to accomplish this.

As to whether or not your current solution with a `static` helper class + method, I think that smells worse than checking `ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` from razor. I commented that you should download the source code for the `ValidationSummary` `HtmlHelper` and look into retooling it to suit your needs, which is probably the best answer to your question. You could essentially encapsulate the aforementioned `if` statement into a custom `HtmlHelper`, which is an appropriate place to put code for view concerns.

Comment: Finally had a chance to take a good look at it again. "... is a view concern." That makes sense. Thank you.